# template function returning void

Tags: c++, templates

I have the following function in my logging class:

```
template<class T> 
inline T ErrLog(T ret, const char* Format, ...)
{
    va_list args; va_start( args, Format ); _vsnprintf(mypWorkBuffer, MaxLogLength, Format, args); va_end(args);
    // do some fancy logging with mypWorkBuffer
    return ret;
}
```

(mypWorkBuffer is defined elsewhere)

This is a very handy shortcut to me cause I can log an error and exit in one line which makes the code more readable by getting error handling out of the way:

```
int f(x) {
   if (x<0) return ErrLog(-1, "f error, %d too small", x);
   ...
}
```

(instead of

```
int f(x) {
   if (x<0) {
      Log("f error, %d too small", x);
      return -1;
   }
   ...
}
```

)

The problem I have is if f returns void. I would like to do

```
void f(x) {
   if (x<0) return ErrLog(void, "f error, %d too small", x);
   ...
}
```

But this does not compile.

I thought about specialization, that is adding:

```
inline void ErrLog(const char* Format, ...)
{
    va_list args; va_start( args, Format ); _vsnprintf(mypWorkBuffer, MaxLogLength, Format, args); va_end(args);
    // do some fancy logging with mypWorkBuffer
    return;
}
```

This allows me to do

```
return ErrLog("f error, %d too small", x);
```

However I'm not sure it's safe for functions returning char*. For example consider:

```
char* f(x) {
   if (x<0) return ErrLog("error", "f error , %d too small", x);
   ...
}
```

I think this one will match both template and specialization.

Any thoughts/better solutions ?

Comment: Why does `ret` even get passed through `ErrLog`? If it's not used or modified it doesn't really have any business being there. Doubly so when it's the only reason for this being a template.

Comment: You misspelled `throw`.

Comment: etheranger - ret is being returned, that's the whole point

n.m. there is no try catch throw here, not sure what you refer to

Comment: You may name the 2 functions with different name.

Comment: "there is no try catch throw here". That's exactly the problem.

Comment: n.m. these one liners don't help, I don't understand what you mean

Comment: The log function should just do one thing, i.e. log and not use any extra parameters so the template is unnecessary. When you want to return after a Log line than just return and accept that it is not a one liner. IMO not beeing creative here keeps the code simpler.

Comment: A function that could not, for any reason, fulfill its contract should throw. Not return a nonsense value.

Comment: n.m, I asked a specific question derived from a code base that does not use exception handling which is just one way of dealing with errors. 
Returning error code from function is common practice in C/C++ even if you don't like it.
Your comments are off the point and not helpful.

Comment: Returning error codes is one (not the best) way of handling errors, so why are you hardcoding it into your logging function? If it's not your logging function but rather your error-handling function, what does it do in a function returning void? How does such a function report errors?

Comment: It logs an error and exit, with an error code if relevant. what's so hard to get ? some functions (ie top level server api in my case, have no one to pass the error to, they log and die).

Comment: Yes, when someone calls a function that can fail and doesn't bother to check the result, it's somewhat hard to get. Why call it in the first place if you don't care if it succeeds or not? But I guess I'll have to live with that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think it is more idiomatic and much, much simpler to just use the comma operator:

```
inline void Errlog(const char *format,...) { /* ... */ }

void f(int x) {
    if (x<0) return Errlog("f error...");
}

double g(double x) {
    if (x<0) return Errlog("x is negative..."),-1.0;
    else return sqrt(x);
}
```

The left hand size of the comma operator can be a `void` expression.

This obviates the need to use a templated function at all.

**Edit: if you really don't like using comma...**

You have three options if you really want to use a function interface.
Given a generic function (I'm using `std::forward` here, so that we can use it with references and so on):

```
template <class T>
inline T &&ErrLog(T &&ret,const char *format,...) {
    /* logging ... */
    return std::forward<T>(ret);
}
```

You can either:

1) Use a separate function for the void case.

```
void ErrLogV(const char *format,...) {
    /* logging ... */
}

void foo1(int x) {
    if (x<0) return ErrLogV("foo1 error");
}
```

2) Overload with a special 'tag' type:

```
static struct errlog_void_t {} errlog_void;

inline void ErrLog(errlog_void_t,const char *format,...) {
    /* logging ... */
}

void foo2(int x) {
    if (x<0) return ErrLog(errlog_void,"foo2 error");
}
```

3) Or use a throw away argument and cast to void:

```
void foo3(int x) {
    // uses generic ErrLog():
    if (x<0) return (void)ErrLog(0,"foo3 error");
}
```

**Second edit: why the version without the ret parameter can't work**

You can safely define the version with `ret`; it's not ambiguous, but it won't necessarily be used when you want it to be. The fundamental problem is that in one context you will want one behaviour, and in another the other behaviour, but the function call parameters will have the exact same type.

Consider the following example:

```
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
T &&foo(T &&x,const char *format,...) {
    puts("T-version");
    va_list va;
    va_start(va,format);
    vprintf(format,va);
    va_end(va);
    puts("");
    return forward<T>(x);
}

void foo(const char *format,...) {
    puts("void-version");
    va_list va;
    va_start(va,format);
    vprintf(format,va);
    va_end(va);
    puts("");
}

int main() {
    foo("I want the void overload: %s, %s","some string","some other string");
    foo("I want to return this string","I want the const char * overload: %s","some string");
}
```

This will compile! But only the first version of `foo` will be called. The compiler cannot distinguish your intent from the argument types.

Why is it not ambiguous?

Both versions of `foo` will be candidates for overload resolution, but the first one will be a better match. You can refer to a [detailed description of the process](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/overload_resolution) (especially the section on ranking), but in short, when you have two or more `const char *` arguments, the `const char *` second parameter of the first version of `foo` is more specific than the ellipsis parameter of the second version.

If you have only one `const char *` argument, then the void-returning version will win over the generic one, because non-template overloads are prefered to template-overloads, other things being equal:

```
foo("this will use the void-version");
```

In short, using the overload will compile, but will give surprising and hard to debug behaviour, and can't handle the case where your `void`-returning version takes more than one argument.

Comment: I don't see the point of what OP is trying to achieve, but the comma operator? Why wouldn't you just put it in a block?

Comment: I believe the OP is trying to have a way of logging these sorts of error-return situations which minimally clutters the code. For example, a block can't be used in the middle of another expression, and with most coding style conventions, would replace one line with two to four.

Comment: yes exactly, my code is meant to give a one liner log and return, to avoid cluttering the code with error handling blocks

Interesting use of the comma ! but this is highly unusual and IMO confusing so looking for something better

Comment: Comma is great; everyone should know how it works so they don't get surprised :) Nonetheless, amended answer with what I think are your three alternatives, keeping a function-only interface.

Comment: 2 and 3 are useful, thx ! if nothing better comes along I'll mark this as the answer

Comment: allthogh I still might use the specilization at the end of my post which will work except for the char* case, and hope the compiler will give me an error then .. (still have to veify that)

Comment: I've added another section demonstrating the problem with the specialization option.

Comment: @halfflat: The other alternative to comma is to make `ErrLog` always return `true` and write `if (error_condition && ErrLog(fmt, ...)) return return_value;`

Answer (score 0):

For the `void` question, use an int specialization returning `0` and later ignore it :

```
void f(x) {
   if (x<0) {
      ErrLog(0, "f error, %d too small", x);
      return;
   }
   ...
}
```

For functions returning `char *` you can make it safe provided the returned value is static (but as you are using C++ you could alse use `std::string`) :

```
char* f(x) {
   static char err[] = "error";
   if (x<0) return ErrLog(err, "f error , %d too small", x);
   ...
}
```

EDIT :

For the `void` part, I cannot imagine how you can avoid a block (independantly of the templating question) :

```
void g(int x);
void f(int x) {
    if (x<0) return g(x); // 2 errors here : g returns void and f returns void
}
```

If a function `g` returns void, you cannot use it as the value of a return statement, whatever this function is. And anyway you cannot use a `return something;` in a function returning `void`. The best I can imagine (but it is not what you asked) is :

```
void f(x) {
   if (x<0) ErrLog(0, "f error, %d too small", x);
   else {
      ...
   }
}
```

creating another block for the else part ...

Comment: the whole point is to avoid a block and a separate return
so I can just have a one line if (x<0) return ErrLog( ...

Comment: @kofifus : I can understand your wish, but the compiler won't allow you to use `return x;` in a `void` returning function ... I've edited my post

Comment: a function returning void can def return another function returning void, so your f functions compiles fine (at least in VS2013)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use template specialization with a user defined Void type, for handling your Void case.
Sorry this is C++14, but you should be able to convert it really easily, just change the return types accordingly

```
template<class T>
auto ErrLog(T ret, const char* Format, ...)
{
    return ret;
}

struct Void{ };

template<>
auto ErrLog(Void ret, const char* Format, ...)
{
    return;
}

int main()
{
    ErrLog(Void{}, "f error, %d too small");
    ErrLog(-1, "f error, %d too small");
}
```

Also I didn't pass the variadic template Args, this solution is more to show you this idea.

Comment: indeed, just a bit more concise and without a comma operator overload :-)